# Spring JpaRepository manyToMany bidirectional should save instead of update

Tags: spring, jpa, save, many-to-many, bidirectional

if got a language table and a system table with a many-to-many relationship:

Language:

```
@JsonAutoDetect
@Entity
@Table(name = "language")
public class Language implements Serializable {   

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "language_id", nullable = false)
    private int languageId;


    @Column(name = "language_name", nullable = false)
    private String languageName;

    @Column(name = "language_isocode", nullable = false)
    private String languageIsoCode;


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "system_language", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "language_id", updatable = false)},
        inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "system_id", updatable = false)}, uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
            "language_id",
            "system_id"
        })})
    private List<System> systems;


    public Language() {

    }

    // GETTER & SETTERS 
   // ....

}
```

System

```
@JsonAutoDetect
@Entity
@Table(name = "system")
public class System implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @Column(name = "system_id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer systemId;


    @Column(name = "system_name", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String systemName;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "university_id", nullable = false)
    private University university;

    @JoinColumn(name = "calender_id", nullable = false)
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Calendar calender;    

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "system")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<SystemUserRole> systemUserRoleList;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "system")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<Role> roleList;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "system")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private CsmUserEntity csmUserEntity;    


    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "systems")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<Language> languages;


    public System() {

    }

   // GETTER & SETTERS 
   // ....

}
```

When im writing a first dataset (systemId=1, language_id=20) into the table, everything works fine. But when i try to write a second dataset with the same language_id but with other system_id (systemId=2, language_id=20), then the existing dataset gets updated. But i want to have a new dataset instead. What can i do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The relevant code would be that which constructs and saves these entities. Can you add?